# Porting from Android to IOS with Google j2objc

Tags: android, ios, gwt, j2objc

I know how android system works and haved already created some applications, and I have an accademical knowledge about IOS. I have to create a mobile application for both Android and IOS platforms, so I was thinking to use the Google j2objc tool. 
I don't have to create the web application, so I don't need GWT.
In this case, is j2objc the right choice?
Otherwise, can you suggest me better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably suspect there is no simple answer for your question. You have many other option and it depends on your experience and other circumstances which one is the best for your needs.

Give it a try and you will see!